# How to get data related from another table django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, relationship

I have three model Pesticide, Disease and Instruction what i want is to get all **disease** with relation to **pesticide** which relate to **instruction** model

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pesticide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Treatment(models.Model):
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, related_name='treatments', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    pesticide = models.ForeignKey(Pesticide, related_name='treatments', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.instruction
```

and serializer

```
class PesticideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Pesticide
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pesticides = PesticideSerializer(source='treatment_set', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = [

            'id',
            'name',
            'pesticides',
           
        ]
```

My problem is that i can not get pesticides in **django serializer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pesticides = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_pesticides(self, disease):
        pesticide_qs = Pesticide.objects.filter(treatments__disease=disease)
        return PesticideSerializer(pesticide_qs, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'pesticides']
```

Comment: I face another question how do i filter to get only single pesticide with instruction based on disease

Comment: better to ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the line `pesticides = PesticideSerializer(source='treatment_set', read_only=True)` in `DiseaseSerializer` to  `pesticides = PesticideSerializer(source='treatment_set', read_only=True, many=True)` will solve your problem (you should add `many=True` because the relation type is one to many).